# Is it advisable to develop and publish an android application without testing it on a real device first?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to develop an android application and publish it. It is a very simple messenger application.

For testing it on a **real device** I would need to buy a android phone first. Normally I would just set up some **virtual devices** with different screen resolutions and different sdk's and start the application on that devices using the **emulator**.

So would you recommend to test the application on a real device? Any other suggestion?

Comment: How would you feel if you had a brand new Android and you downloaded this untested app and things went badly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's advisable. Whenever possible I would test an application on **at least** one device, preferably more. Can you borrow an android phone from a friend for a few hours? If your app is truly simple then you should be able to get someone to part with phone for a short amount of time (then take them out to lunch after :P). Or you could try and snag a cheap used phone off of eBay or a similar site.

The only reason I wouldn't fully trust the emulator is that it can be very slow and unresponsive, especially for games.

Answer (score 5):

> So would you recommend to test the application on a real device?

Absolutely. I think that publishing an Android app without testing on hardware qualifies as insanity.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should to test the application on a real device.  The performance you get on the emulator is going to be very different from a real device, and interacting with the app with a mouse and keyboard is very different from using a touchscreen.

It shouldn't be too hard to borrow one from a friend, or find a cheap, used phone on ebay or craigslist.

Answer (score 3):

I am testing my game on three devices: low-res, hi-res and ultra high resolution tablet, with two different android version 2.1 and 2.2.

I am happy that I spent money on a low resoution samsung phone, because I learned a lot about screen density and a need to laod a bitmap with no scaling option in order to preserve its quality.

For some straight forward layouts with view animations, emulators work pretty well just slower. So it all depends how demanding your applications are... but as soon as it is convinient it would be only logical to get a device.

Answer (score 1):

One of my biggest fears is the fact that I don't have access to multiple devices.  I can only test it on my current phone, so I have no idea how it will react on an older device with lower screen resolution, or android build, and I wont know how it will interact with hardware not on my current phone (trackball, etc.)

Also, with all the different user interfaces (sense, touchwiz, etc), I fear that my color usage may not play well with a particular UI (for instance if I have a very grascale inspired app but the titlebar is a particular color).

Comment: Buy more devices.  Low-end Android phones are dirt cheap these days; I paid €49 for a Samsung Europa a few weeks ago with no contract.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to buy a phone then there are some services that let you use real devices remotely over the web. [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/android.html) has a Pay As You Go pricing plan that is reasonably priced (I don't have any affiliation with them except as a satisfied customer.)

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you want. You can buy 30000 devices but if no one download your app what happens?

The idea is to develop FAST and then improve your app and testing process if the users really like and show some traction to your app. If buying an expensive device makes you unhappy and to program less, then don't buy it! :)